# Should I always prefer working with prepared SQL statements, for performance benefits?

Tags: sql, mysql, odbc, relational-database, prepared-statement

My understanding is that a *prepared statement* is compiled on the server once, thus saving the overhead of repeating parsing, optimization etc. Apparently, I should always prefer using prepared statements for queries that run more than once.

Are there any cons to this approach?

I am using [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) (libodbc++) from C++ to MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html):

> **Why use prepared statements?**
>
> There are numerous advantages to using
>   prepared statements in your
>   applications, both for security and
>   performance reasons.
>
> Prepared statements can help increase
>   security by separating SQL logic from
>   the data being supplied. This
>   separation of logic and data can help
>   prevent a very common type of
>   vulnerability called an SQL injection
>   attack. Normally when you are dealing
>   with an ad hoc query, you need to be
>   very careful when handling the data
>   that you received from the user. This
>   entails using functions that escape
>   all of the necessary trouble
>   characters, such as the single quote,
>   double quote, and backslash
>   characters. This is unnecessary when
>   dealing with prepared statements. The
>   separation of the data allows MySQL to
>   automatically take into account these
>   characters and they do not need to be
>   escaped using any special function.
>
> The increase in performance in
>   prepared statements can come from a
>   few different features. First is the
>   need to only parse the query a single
>   time. When you initially prepare the
>   statement, MySQL will parse the
>   statement to check the syntax and set
>   up the query to be run. Then if you
>   execute the query many times, it will
>   no longer have that overhead. This
>   pre-parsing can lead to a speed
>   increase if you need to run the same
>   query many times, such as when doing
>   many INSERT statements.
>
> (Note: While it will not happen with
>   MySQL 4.1, future versions will also
>   cache the execution plan for prepared
>   statements, eliminating another bit of
>   overhead you currently pay for each
>   query execution.)
>
> The second place where performance may
>   increase is through the use of the new
>   binary protocol that prepared
>   statements can use. The traditional
>   protocol in MySQL always converts
>   everything into strings before sending
>   them across the network. This means
>   that the client converts the data into
>   strings, which are often larger than
>   the original data, sends it over the
>   network (or other transport) to the
>   server, which finally decodes the
>   string into the correct datatype. The
>   binary protocol removes this
>   conversion overhead. All types are
>   sent in a native binary form, which
>   saves the conversion CPU usage, and
>   can also cut down on network usage.
>
> **When should you use prepared statements?** Prepared statements can
>   be useful for all of the above
>   reasons, however they should not (and
>   can not) be used for everything in
>   your application. First off, the type
>   of queries that they work on is
>   limited to DML (INSERT, REPLACE,
>   UPDATE, and DELETE), CREATE TABLE, and
>   SELECT queries. Support for additional
>   query types will be added in further
>   versions, to make the prepared
>   statements API more general.
>
> **-> Sometimes prepared statements can actually be slower than regular
>   queries**. The reason for this is that
>   there are two round-trips to the
>   server, which can slow down simple
>   queries that are only executed a
>   single time. In cases like that, one
>   has to decide if it is worth trading
>   off the performance impact of this
>   extra round-trip in order to gain the
>   security benefits of using prepared
>   statements.

Comment: thanks! So, do you know if the binary protocol mentioned here is implemented in 5.+ versions, and if it needs to be specifically enabled?

Comment: It is implemented: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html   and it does not have to be specifically enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Larger numbers of active prepared statements consume additional server memory. For example, it can be an issue for embedded platforms (e.g. sqlite database on IPhone).

Comment: thanks. How large is "larger"? if I have 10-15 statements, is it ok? I am not on embedded platform.

Comment: There is no single answer. 10-15 statements is definitely ok. 10-15 thousands of statements can be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should always prefer working with prepared statements for the *security* benefits.  They all but eliminate vulnerability to SQL injection, without you having to worry about SQL-escaping values.

If you have a query that doesn't run often, though (less than once per request), a prepared statement can take longer to run.  It takes two calls to use a prepared statement:  once to prepare it, and once to execute it.  With an ad-hoc statement, those two steps are done in one fell swoop, and there's no waiting for the server to say "ok, done compiling".

The upshot of all that being, if you're worried about performance, and your query only runs once, an ad-hoc query might be a little faster.  But the security benefits almost always outweigh the extra little bit of time it takes to prepare a statement.

Comment: thanks. I ask mainly about repeated queries, but security is indeed an additional benefit to consider